# Makefile: Choose the Path for compiling file?

Tags: path, makefile

is it possible in make to choose where the compiled application are saved?
For Example:

My Makefile is in the root folder.
My Source Code is in /src

the compiled application should be saved in

/dist/release/linux

Thanks :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - you can do something like this:

```
VPATH = /src

OUTPUT_DIR = /dist/release/linux

SRC = foo.c bar.c

EXE = foo

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(EXE) : $(SRC)
    gcc -Wall $(SRC) -o $@
```

Note that `VPATH` is a special variable which tells `make` which directories to look in for source files, so it will find `foo.c` and `bar.c` at `/src/foo.c` and `/src/bar.c`.

The executable `foo` will be built at `/dist/release/linux/foo`.